# Spivak Calculus on Manifolds Exercise 2-9

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm kind of stumped on this exercise in two spots.

First I'll state the problem:

Two functions $f,g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are equal up to $n$th order at $a$ if

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - g(a + h)}{h^n} = 0$$

(a) Show that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if there is a function $g$ of the form $g(x) = a_0 + a_1(x-1)$ such that $f$ and $g$ are equal up to the first order at $a$.

(b) If $f'(a), \ldots , f^{(n)}(a)$ exist, show that $f$ and the function $g$ defined by

$$g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i$$

are equal up to $n$th order at $a$. *Hint:* The limit

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i}{(x - a)^n}$$

can be evaluated by L'Hospital's rule.

In part (a), ($\Rightarrow$) I have, but the converse I am just missing a detail. I can't see why

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - a_0 - a_1h}{h} = 0$$

implies that $$a_0 = f(a)$$

I tried adding and subtracting $f(a)$ in the numerator of the limit to see if I could use the triangle inequality or some form of it to show that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a) - a_1h}{h} \leq \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - a_0 - a_1h}{h} = 0$$

but I haven't been able to prove that.

On the other hand, for (b) I used the hint and got that

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i}{(x - a)^n} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f^{n-1}(x) - f^{n-1}(a)}{(n-1)!(x-a)} = \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{(n-1)!}$$

and then

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i}{(x - a)^n} = \lim_{x \to a} \left[\frac{f(x) - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i}{(x - a)^n}\right] - \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}\\ = \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{(n-1)!} - \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} \neq 0$$

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**: I calculated the factorial wrong in the denominator. Silly mistake. It is actually:

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i}{(x - a)^n} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f^{n-1}(x) - f^{n-1}(a)}{n!(x-a)} = \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$$

And then

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i}{(x - a)^n} = \lim_{x \to a} \left[\frac{f(x) - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i}{(x - a)^n}\right] - \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}\\ = \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} - \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} = 0$$

Comment: Multiply with $h$. If $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - a_0 - a_1h}{h} = 0$, then certainly $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} f(a+h) - a_0 - a_1 h = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I really need to work on seeing these minor details...I guess it just comes with practice and familiarity, which I never did with calculus.

Comment: Are you sure this is from Manifolds and not from Calculus?

Comment: Yes, this is from Calculus on Manifolds Section 2. It's just that this particular question deals with a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm fairly confused after reading this question. How is $a_0 + a_1x$ of the form $a_0 + a_1(x-1)$?

Comment: I thinhk f must be continuos at a. A counterexample: $$ f(x) = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{lrr}
x  & if &  x \neq 0\\
0 & if & x = 0
\end{array} \right. $$

and $ g(x) = x $ for all $x  \in \mathbb{R}$.

Clearly, f and g are  equal up to first order at $ 0 $ but  f is not differentiable at $ 0 $. Therefore, $ (\Leftarrow)  $ is not true.

Comment: @daisy I think you meant $f(0) \neq 0$, otherwise $f$ and $g$ are the same function.

Answer (score 2):

*From the comments above*.

---

Notice that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - a_0 - a_1 h}{h}=0 \implies \lim_{h \to 0} h \cdot \left( \frac{f(a+h) - a_0 - a_1 h}{h} \right)=0.$$ But the second limit is just
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h) - a_0 - a_1 h = f(a) - a_0,
$$
so we get $f(a) = a_0$.

Also, do note that we assume the continuity of $f$ at $a$ when we calculate the above limit. This is a minor error in part (a) of this problem, since the continuity of $f$ at $a$ is not assumed in the problem as it is stated.